# Can I export or publish an Adobe Director movie to a format that can be played in Adobe AIR?

Tags: air, shockwave, adobe-director

Is it possible to export or publish an Adobe Director movie to a format that can be played in Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 0):

The runtimes offer widely different featuresets, I'm going to go with no.